# After uprading to Visual Studio 16.11.1, Xamarin Forms broke XALNS7028: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.iOS'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

### ERROR

I am building a Xamarin.Form project and I am compiling the Android Project when this error comes out, which is ironic because this is an IOS related Error.

### WHAT I DID

It was working fine the night before. This morning, I upgraded VS to 16.11.1. Then I compiled the projects. When I compile my Android Project, this error comes out. Compiling other projects (e.g. The Forms project) work fine.

### WHAT I HAVE DONE

I have searched the internet for solutions (most solutions are old ones, but I tried anyway). I have done the following:

- Restarted my Computer
- Closed VS Studio, deleted the obj, bin and .vs folder in all projects and the restarted Visual Studio
- Cleared a redownloaded nuget packages and recompiled.
- Upgraded to latest version of Xamarin and all latest nuget packages
- Restored my older project (from last night) via github (git clone) and tried to compile.
  *None of the above worked*

### REFERENCES

Here is the full error copy-pasted=>

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XALNS7028: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.iOS.dll'
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 221
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 191
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type) in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs:line 110
at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve() in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/TypeReference.cs:line 276
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionCache.Resolve(TypeReference typeReference) in /Users/builder/azdo/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionCache.cs:line 20
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.<GetTypeAndBaseTypes>d_5.MoveNext() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line 40
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.IsSubclassOf(TypeDefinition type, String typeName, IMetadataResolver resolver) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line 94
at MonoDroid.Tuner.FixAbstractMethodsStep.FixAbstractMethodsUnconditional(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssembliesNoShrink.RunTask()
at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 0
```

Comment: You probably need to go back to *first principles* here. Have you tried to create a new project and see if you still get the same error? This error is seemingly not *code dependent* and more to do with *tooling*, if you can reproduce it in a new project, well your stuffed. If you cant, well you have a path forward

Comment: Thank you I am currently doing that but it seems the problem still persists.....I have reported to Microsoft, it seems more and more people are seeing this problem as I have seen an official ticket in MS docs

Comment: If you create a ticket, you might just either put it in your question or self answer with the information you have and the link, maybe leave it unaccepted as someone might have a work around. If it ever gets solved, welll  you know what to do

Comment: It's 100% a bug... a big one.. as everyone who upgrade to latest VS problem will see this

Comment: Why am I being thumbs down?

Comment: I just upvoted, this is a legit question and issue, and nothing wrong with it

Comment: Has anyone tried downgrading their installation? I'm a bit scared to do it as VS may break

Comment: You could try it to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Did you try to unload the iOS project from the solution, did you get the same error? If it works, then you might be able to just change your solution's build config to remove the iOS project from being included when the config is set to Android

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound dumb but I got mine working after many hours by adding the Xamarin.iOS to my References area. You may need to browse to it.
My location was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Xamarin.iOS.dll

Xamarin.iOS did not exist in the assemblies selection area.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an Visual Studio issue, you can report it as the following shows:[image]

Comment: Yes, a lot of people are seeing this... let's see how fast Microsoft is going to act!

Comment: I have reported it too